# binding two SQL statements within single Method using ArrayList in (SQL & C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, arraylist, binding

i want to show list of `SemesterID` based on `StudentID` as shown below.

in comboBox1 i have listed `StudentIDs` but give me an Errors:

Error #1

> Con is not closed.

Error #2

> DataReader is Already in use...

```
public void bindStudentID()
{
    try
    {
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT studentId FROM tbStudent",     con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            a.Add(dr["studentId"]);
        }
        comboBox1.DataSource = a;


        ArrayList aa = new ArrayList();
        SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SemesterID FROM tbSemester     Where StudentID='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader drr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (drr.Read())
        {
            aa.Add(drr["SemesterID"]);
            comboBox2.DataSource = aa;
        }
        con.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the reader like this:

```
// Call Close when done reading.
reader.Close();
```

try using this syntax for your connection, it's safer:

```
    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ReadSingleRow((IDataRecord)reader);
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but you have to resolve your errors first to solve what you want

Comment: why do you use ArrayList? I don't think that's the right way to do what you want... your question is not clear... write what exactly do you want to accomplish in this method

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work fine. This code is explains itself. You were creating a SqlDataReader object without disposing previous one.

```
public void bindStudentID()
{
    try
    {
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT studentId FROM tbStudent",     con);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            a.Add(dr["studentId"]);
        }
        comboBox1.DataSource = a;

        ArrayList aa = new ArrayList();
        SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SemesterID FROM tbSemester     Where StudentID='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", con);
        dr = null;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            aa.Add(drr["SemesterID"]);

        }
        comboBox2.DataSource = aa;
        con.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

Please mark as answer if I helped

Answer (score 0):

check this,

```
SqlDataReader drr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

it should be

```
SqlDataReader drr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
```

you are using **cmd** instead of **cmdd** command

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.80).aspx) says:

> You should always call the Close method when you have finished using the DataReader object.
>   If your Command contains output parameters or return values, they will not be available until the DataReader is closed.
>   Note that while a DataReader is open, the Connection is in use exclusively by that DataReader. You cannot execute any commands for the Connection, including creating another DataReader, until the original DataReader is closed.

So based on MSDN, try this:

```
public void bindStudentID()
{
//instantiating a ArrayList object does not need to be included inside Try/Catch block
//try
//{
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
try
{
    //Before opening the connection make sure that connection's current state is not open, otherwise you will get exception
    //con.Open();
 if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
 {
     con.Close();
 }
 con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT studentId FROM tbStudent",     con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        a.Add(dr["studentId"]);
    }
    comboBox1.DataSource = a;

 //You should close data reader before using it again or defining new one
    dr.Close();

    ArrayList aa = new ArrayList();
 //No need to define new SqlCommand object and you can use the prev one
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SemesterID FROM tbSemester     Where StudentID='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", con);

 //No need to define new SqlDataREader object and you can use the prev one
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        aa.Add(dr["SemesterID"]);
       //I think this should be stated out of the while block            
       //comboBox2.DataSource = aa;
    }
   comboBox2.DataSource = aa;
     //You should close data reader before using it again or defining new one
    dr.Close();
//Close the connection in finally block        
//con.Close();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
 //You should also close the connection even if an exception raised
        con.Close();

}
}
```